# Trouble with rake db:setup

Tags: ruby, postgresql, github

I am trying to pull a GitHub file using `rake db:setup`, but I get an error every time, no matter how many times I reinstall [postgresql [image: Install postgresql]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/postgresql) or check Rails. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
hifriend@ubuntu:~/refugerestrooms$ sudo -u root -H bundle exec \
  rake db:setup --trace
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load_if_ruby (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:72:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `block in create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:181:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:181:in `each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:85:in `create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"bathrooms_development", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil}
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:72:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `block in create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:181:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:181:in `each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:85:in `create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"bathrooms_test", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost"}
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:schema:load_if_ruby
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:624:in `block in method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:617:in `method_missing'
/home/hifriend/refugerestrooms/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:42:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:42:in `define'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:62:in `define'
/home/hifriend/refugerestrooms/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:253:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:260:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience with ruby on rails, but by reading the output I suspect that it is a password problem.

line 8 reads:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

And then towards the middle:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"bathrooms_development", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil}
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

It seems that the server is expecting a password in order to establish the connection but you are not supplying one in the connection string. If i remember correctly, it is recommended to use a "open" (ie without password) account while developing your RoR application.

I suggest you create a db user with <del>all admin</del>*(bad idea, sorry)* `create` privileges but without password and use that account for development purposes. Do this on a local/test instance of the postgres server to avoid exposing any data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the database adapter settings to your Postgres server in the `config/database.yml` file. Use something like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: my_app_db 
  schema_search_path: my_app_schema, public
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: my_user
  password: my_pass
```

For more details on setting up Rails with Postgres you can try [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres).